# I need help I am trying to update the user profile React & Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, file-upload, axios

So I am trying to update user profile but the backend tells me the data is unprocessable. This happens because in the headers I used the content type `multipart/form-data`. I did this nbecause I need to update the image too.

When I change the content type from `multipart/form-data` to `application/json` it works, but the image won't change and I get "image required"

This is the code:

[image]

[image]

I am expecting to update user info.

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i did provide the front end code and backend code

Comment: Could you please share the error you get when sending the image as multipart/form-data ?

also what exactly is userInfo.image in the frontend  (an object, string, a html element)?

Comment: userInfo is the object that contain the data that I am sending to back-end

Comment: message: 'The username field is required. (and 3 more errors)
this the message from the axios data ,but the thing I did debug the formdata and all the inputs are filled the thing is with multipart/form-data so if I change it to application/json the username ,email,password will change but the image no

Comment: The problem is how you send the request in regards to the image. So please update the question. Laravel knows how to decode the request depending on the content type. Try it with postman to confirm the php part works fine.

Comment: i try it with postman but it still the same problem